# infinite while loop with screen click issue

Tags: python-3.x

### Python clip

Here's a clip of the code. I'm getting an infinite loop problem where it keeps repeating player turn without going to `check_click()` even when the screen is clicked. Is there something I did wrong? or is there an alternative way of doing this?

```
import turtle as trtl
turn = ''
player = ''
enemy = ''
wn = trtl.Screen()

def check_click(x,y):
    global turn
    turn = ''
    input()

def player_turn():
    global player, enemy, turn
    draw_box()
    turn = 'player'
    while turn == 'player':
        wn.listen()
        wn.onscreenclick(check_click)

player_turn()
wn.mainloop()
```

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'onscreenclick ()' sets up an event handler. In your case 'check_click ()'. It only needs to be called once. Also it is a method belonging to 'turtle' not 'Screen'. Try it like this :

```
import turtle as trtl 

wn = trtl.Screen() 
turn = ''
  
def check_click (x, y) : 
    global turn
    if turn == 'player' :
        turn = 'not player'
    else :
        turn = 'player'
    print (turn)

trtl.onscreenclick (check_click)
trtl.done ()
```